# How can I find out how much BIOS ROM memory a motherboard have (for Ryzen 3rd gen support)

Tags: motherboard, bios, hardware-rec

How can I find out how much BIOS ROM memory, a specific motherboard have, when in the specs of most motherboards it isn't listed ?

I'm searching to buy Motherboard with 32MB BIOS ROM, but I can't see anywhere listed information about how much BIOS ROM size any Model of motherboard have.

---

There was problems with some Motherboards being unable to support the new Ryzen 3-rd generations CPU's, because there was not enough memory in the 16MB BIOS ROM chips. And manufacturers had to cut functionality of the mobos

Comment: Only way is to ask each manufacturer about any boards you are considering.

Comment: If you already own the board and have windows installed you can check what size it is....https://superuser.com/questions/806226/how-to-see-rom-size

Comment: There is no reason for it to be listed that a normal user would care about. 32MB sounds shockingly large for what is effectively setup and boot code. 32megabit (Mb) would probably be slightly on the large side but not outside the realms of possibility but 32 megabytes (MB) sounds unreasonably large and completely unnecessary. What problem are you trying to solve? If you are trying to fit a mini operating system into the boot ROM then you are probably looking in the wrong place to do it, this is what storage devices are for.

Comment: The best place to find out boot rom sizes would probably be to go to the support site for each motherboard and then download and extract the firmware updates. The file size of the firmware update file is probably a good indication of how much space is in the chip.

Comment: @Mokubai There was problems with some Motherboards being unable to support the new Ryzen 3-rd generations CPU's, because there was not enough memory in the 16MB BIOS ROM chips. And manufacturers had to cut functionality of the mobos.

Answer (score 1):

Most are 16MB.  You could buy a board and swap out the chip - you should be able to get a 32MB in the same family of chips, with the same pin out.

Comment: Can you add some examples? Can the IC be easily pulled or does it need to be soldered? How do you flash your ROM on to a new blank IC? Sounds like special tools are required.